# Convert strange timeformat to time

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Well i'm grabbing a datetime (time field) from SharePoint and i have this output => 2014-07-30T15:00:00Z

How is it possible to make this a valid time. Even the timezone is incorrect of the values i have picked.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to convert this!

That seems to be a valid ISO8601 formatted moment!
So u can just use `new Date("2014-07-30T15:00:00Z")` to get a valid JS Date object.

Please note: the Z at the end indicates its in UTC TimeZone. Since JS always works in the local TimeZone it will convert this UTC value to the corresponding local time. So for me (currently in UTC+2) I will get the following:

```
var myDate = new Date("2014-07-30T15:00:00Z");
myDate; // Wed Jul 30 2014 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
myDate.getTimezoneOffset(); // -120
myDate.toISOString(); // "2014-07-30T15:00:00.000Z"
```

As u can see just the formatted information for the user are in local format. Use the UTC functions on `Date` to get and manipulate the UTC information.

```
myDate.getUTCHours()
```

Generally if u handle with Dates in JS check out moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Probably some javascript GURU will tell you that my approach is wrong but it would be easyest to extract values to different variables and then you can do whatever you want with them.

Here is a simple example:

```
var YourGivenTime = "2014-07-30T15:00:00Z";
var d = YourGivenTime.replace(/\T/g, "-").replace(/\Z/g, "").split('-');
// ["2014", "07", "30", "15:00:00"]

var Year = d[0];
var Day = d[1];
var Month = d[2];
var Time = d[3];

console.log ("Year - " + Year);
console.log ("Day - " + Day);
console.log ("Month - " + Month);
console.log ("Time - " + Time);
```

Please be noted that those console.log lines are not mandatory and they are there only to visualize you the result in the browsers console.

BR's